# Изображение кривой Безье в Delphi

Tags: delphi, графика

Задача: написать программу по изображению кривой Безье по заданным точкам. Опорные точки задаются щелчком по канве. При выполнении программы происходит ошибка и компилятор выдает:"Floating point invalid operation".
При игнорировании этого, изображается кривая весьма отдаленно напоминающая искомую. В чем ошибка?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
 Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  xtoch, ytoch: array[0..100] of integer;
  kolvoopor,kolvotochek,koordx,koordy:integer;
  step,tekstep:real;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}


function faktorial(chislo:integer):integer;
var i:integer;
begin
if chislo = 0 then
result:=1
else
begin
for i := 1 to chislo do
chislo:=chislo*i;
result:=chislo;
end;
end;

function bernstein(n,i:integer;t:real):real;
begin
  result:=(faktorial(n)/(faktorial(i)*faktorial(n-i)))*power(t,i)*power((1-t),(n-i));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form1.Close;
end;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
   kolvoopor:=0;
   end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const sz=3;
begin
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
   Image1.Canvas.Ellipse(X - sz, Y - sz, X + sz, Y + sz);
  kolvoopor:=kolvoopor+1;
  xtoch[kolvoopor]:=X;
  ytoch[kolvoopor]:=Y;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
 i: Integer;
 begin
 kolvotochek:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
 step:=1/kolvotochek;
 koordx:=0;
 koordy:=0;
 tekstep:=step;
 Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color:= clred;
 Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(xtoch[0],ytoch[0]);
 repeat

   for i := 0 to kolvoopor do
     begin
     koordx:=koordx+round(xtoch[i]*bernstein(kolvoopor,i,tekstep));
     koordy:=koordy+round(ytoch[i]*bernstein(kolvoopor,i,tekstep));
     end;


tekstep:=tekstep+step;

Image1.Canvas.LineTo(koordx,koordy);
koordx:=0;
koordy:=0;
until tekstep = 1;
end;



end.
```

Разобрался. В процедуре Form1.FormCreate kolvoopor должно быть равным минус один. Правда остается проблема с тем, что кривая выходит дальше последней опорной точки. Как можно оформить выход из цикла при достижении последней точки?
Кстати "floating point invalid operation" осталось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас накапливается погрешность, когда вы прибавляете `tekstep := tekstep + step;` чтобы выйти из цикла и избавиться от "floating point invalid operation" вам надо применять не строгое условие `=1` а `>=1`:

```
until tekstep >= 1+step;
```

`+step` - это, чтобы достичь последней точки